# Type assertion is not working after parsing from local storage

Tags: angular, typescript, type-assertion

In my angular project I stored an array of data points in the local storage.

For the data I created a class like so:

```js
export class Datapoint {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  // ... some more properties.

  constructor(){
  }

  public getDescription() {
    // ... logic
  }

  // ... more functions
}
```

Now I retrieve the array from the local storage and parses it back from string.

```js
const dpList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('datapoints'));
```

Because 'dpList' is of type 'Object' I make a type assertion to my type 'Datapoint'.

```js
const datapoints: Datapoint[] = [];

public someFunction(): Datapoint[] {
  // Get the stringified objects from the local storage.
  const dpList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('datapoints'));

  // Iterate through the array and push to this.datapoints.
  dpList.forEach(dp => {
    const asserted_dp: Datapoint = (dp as Datapoint);
    this.datapoints.push(asserted_dp);
  });
}
```

But the asserted_dp is after the type assertion of type Object and not Datapoint as I expected it would be. And so I can't access the functions of type Datapoint because the **proto** property has no information about them.

How can I get the type assertion to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Understanding the Issue**

Local storage only stores strings. While you may have stringified your Datapoint objects for storage, when you `JSON.parse` the string, it doesn't return an instance of `Datapoint`, instead it gives you a normal javascript `Object` type. This is important because your object no longer has your `Datapoint` methods such as `getDescription`, so you can't just cast the type.

**Potential solution**

I would recommend creating a loader that reconstructs instances of your `Datapoint`from your serialized string. I don't know how you normally construct your data points but I'll give a simple example here

```
function loadDatapoints(): Datapoint[] {
    var dp_objects: any = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('datapoints'));
    var points: Datapoint[] = [];

    for (var i: number = 0; i < dp_objects.length; i++) {
        var point: Datapoint = new Datapoint();
        // However you normally construct Datapoints...
        points.push(point);
    }

    return points;
}
```

This way you're actually working with Datapoint instances and therefore type assertion now work as expected.

Comment: That was the workaround I thought of too. I created a function and looped through the array with a 'for if' loop. In it I copied every property value to the new datapoint. However I still don't understand why the type assertion with the 'as' keyword doesn't work. The general structure of the JSON object is the same as in the Datapoint class. Nonetheless I mark this as answer 'cause it solves the problem.

Comment: It is because when you `stringify` objects, you get your data properties, but you do not receive your functions. You can't actually `stringify` a class, you can only `stringify` data objects. If you try to stringify a data object with functions, the functions will be stripped. So with that being said, `JSON.parse` will only ever give you a JavaScript object. Therefore, you lose context of the original prototype. Once you `JSON.parse` you're working with a completely different interface now.

Comment: You also have to remember that TypeScript simply compiles down to JavaScript. So you're executing run-time code doesn't have your TypeScript typings or interfaces, apart of what is natively available in JavaScript. TypeScript is purely to enforce strict-type ruling at compiler time, but doesn't do anything at run-time. So you can't actually cast a type from one type to another not in a traditional sense. All you're doing is telling the compiler to "trust me, this variable is actually this interface X instead of interface Y".